# Wolfram Data Drop support for Unicode

Tags: wolfram-cloud, unicode, datadrop

Does Wolfram Data Drop support Unicode?

If I enter an entry manually, for example "пример", it will not work. If I upload the file and try to read it using ReadList, or Import, it will not work, all showing gibberish.

Does the Wolfram Development Platform support Unicode at all? If yes, are bug fixes planned for these cases? It makes the platform unusable for languages other than English.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Is adding `Compress`/`Uncompress` fine as a workaround?

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning that maybe the databin does support Unicode, but *Mathematica* doesn't (*Mathematica* has so far not been updated since Unicode was standardized, so uses a pre-standard implementation of UTF-16, whereas everything else now uses UTF-8). The values you get back seem like complete rubbish though, so not sure that the databin doesn't have problems too.

Comment: @OleksandrR. But it can handle characters from the basic multilingual plane just fine. It only has problems with surrogate pairs, which are not needed for Cyrillic, and very rarely needed even for huge character sets like Chinese. And it can import/export UTF-8 encoded text just fine.  LibraryLink even uses UTF-8, and MathLink supports it too.  It seems like this is a specific failing of the Databin service, not of Mathematica core itself.

Comment: @Szabolcs okay, thanks for the clarification. I had forgotten the precise nature of the issues it has. The output almost looks like an attempt to interpret UTF-8 in some native code page, but I wasn't able to discern which combination of code pages produce this result.

Comment: The problem is that even uploading the file to the Cloud and trying to read it using Import or ReadList also does not work. However, when I send an HTTP request to a URL that has Unicode characters, it reads it correctly. If I try to use them in UI components, it does not work. Very frustrating.

Comment: @Kuba, how do I compress from another programming language? Is this some famous compressing?

Comment: I'm obviously missing your point so let me delete those comments to not confuse future readers.

Comment: Yes, maybe I was not really clear, also.